# Open Android App button does not return to the current Activity already open

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

**See Update 2 for current Problem regarding of Activity Launch Mode**

I am developing an Android app. Now I have the problem that once I open a new activity (that is not the activity with `android.intent.action.MAIN` and `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`) in the app, and then press home button, and then press the app icon, the app does not navigate me back to the new activity I have already open (and shown on recent app list). Instead, it open a new MAIN activity.

What should I do to change this behaviour?

===================================================

**Update**

Code for Start Activity Other from Main Activity

```
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LocalActivity.class));
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppDrawTheme"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LocalActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
```

===================================================

**Update 2**

I solve the problem by change 
`android:launchMode="singleInstance"`
to
`android:launchMode="singleTask"`

Although I do not understand why `singleInstance` would be a problem.
How should I understand what Google write on the Android document *"except that the system doesn't launch any other activities into the task holding the instance"* ?

Comment: You could store the last Activity Class inside the preferences for example and then in the onCreate of MAIN, look at this key in the preferences, and run the right activity.

Comment: By default, android will do what you are expecting it to do unless you are doing something in the activity that would prevent that from happening. Can you provide more information regarding what you are doing in the main activity and the activity that you launch from the main one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you are setting `Intent` flags that cause this when you call `startActivity()` or you use activity's properties in `AndroidManifest.xml` that cause this. I would need to see your manifest or code to point where is the problem exactly.

**Updated**

Google docs also says:

> The activity is always the single and only member of its task.

You should go through [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) and read carefully about tasks and activities.

Basically, when you start your main activity it's created within new task. Next activities are placed in the same task(in the stack). Now, the crucial part, Android does not restore only single activity but entire task. This is default.

In case you use `singleInstance` every Activity has own Task and when you start app again(after HOME button) Android restore Task with root Activity, not the one with your last seen Activity. Be very careful when you change launchMode, if it's not clear how it works then you should probably find it out first, otherwise you may have more surprises in the future.

I hope it's clear now for you, if not please read [linked](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `onPause()` and `onResume()` in your activity.